# Can I make a javascript getter that relies on an asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript

I have a tremendous amount of other people's code that, I'm sorry, cannot be refactored for social reasons.  Currently the server generates a variable for this code and delivers it with the page by stuffing it in a script block.  Unfortunately, for performance reasons I now want the creation of this variable to be deferred until after the page is loaded, and if I can skip creating the variable altogether, even better.

So this is the age old "how do I block?" question for javascript, but since I can't refactor the code, I can't just go in and replace every instance of the variable with a promise.

Given how other questions about blocking Javascript tend to be answered, I'm not convinced finding a way to make a getter block until the ajax call is complete is the right answer.  I am open to all suggestions but I wanted this to be a specific question.

Thank you.

Edit: Example.  Here's code I can't touch, also, I can't touch it:

```
if (globalObject.someVariable) {
  doStuff();
} else {
  doOtherStuff();
}
```

Here's what the server puts in the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.extend(globalObject, {
  "someVariable" : true;
}
</script>
```

That I can touch.  I can make someVariable anything I want.  The example just shows true or false, but generating that true or false is a metaphor for 20% of my page load times.  All the parts of the page that need the variable to display already fail gracefully, so it's not a problem to tell them "wait for this variable to finish loading"  I just don't know how, since I can't touch the part of the code where it would be most appropriate to change it.

Comment: It sounds like you're using JSONp, which is fine. You must specify the callback name when the request is sent, you can't defer it. That shouldn't be an issue though as you can just generate a random name. Can you show us why you think you need to defer it? You can always use XMLHTTPRequest instead of JSONp.

Comment: This question is way too vague. Please give some concrete examples.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to add blocking I/O to an asynchronous setup. If this is the point of your _refactor_ I would suggest you have a good talk with your fellow developers.

Comment: @Halcyon, actually I want the opposite.  Currently our server delays sending the page until the variable is created, which wastes a lot of time since a lot of our pages never even use the information.  I want it to send the page, have the page load, and then, if the variable is actually needed, fetch it on demand, instead of generating it every time.

Comment: So you'll get the ago old "you cannot block javascript" answer. No, you cannot use an async value without adapting the code that uses it.

Comment: @Bergi I can adapt the code a little bit, I just have places I can adapt the code and places I can't adapt the code.

Comment: Also, it's not true that you can't block in Javascript.  You can block just fine with callbacks, promises, or generators.

Comment: @Tarbox: Callbacks and promises do *not* block.

Comment: @Bergi Then I don't need to block.

Comment: Load the JSONp file `ondocumentready`, or when you need it.

Comment: @Halcyon Thank you, definitely a sign I was wearing blinkers on this.  Could you make that a real answer so I can accept it?  Also, provide a short example?  I can find plenty on the internet but I'd appreciate seeing exactly what you're imagining.

Comment: @Tarbox: That's the point. But if you need not to block, then you'll need to restructure your code that relies on the json.

Comment: @Tarbox: Make the code that you "cant touch" work with async values. Or be stuck with your slow page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the JSONp file `ondocumentready`, or when you need it.